# Pass a variable from controller to model without using instance variables or arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have overridden the Devise method `send_devise_notification` to be able to send out emails my own way:

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  devise :confirmable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable

  protected

    def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
      # I do lots of crazy stuff here...
    end
end
```

My problem is that I need to pass a variable from my devise controllers to this method in my user model.

If I wanted to share this variable with another method in my controller I would simply set an instance variable:

```rb
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  def create
    @foo = "bar"
    super
  end
end
```

But since instance variables are not passed from my controller to my model this approach will not work.

And since the `send_devise_notification` method is called from all sorts of places by the devise gem I think it could become very complicated to pass it along through arguments.

So how do I pass my variable from controller to model?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to pass something from your controller to your model is by adding a virtual attribute to your model class:

In your models/User.rb file near the top put:

```
attr_accessor :virtual_attribute_name_here
```

Then, in your controller you can set that attribute to whatever you like as though it was an Active Record attribute:

```
@user.virtual_attribute_name_here = "Some thing"
```

Then in your model you can access it in your method as:

```
 def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
   if self.virtual_attribute_name_here == 'Some thing'
     # I do lots of crazy stuff here...
   end
 end
```

Comment: interesting approach. However, since the user isn't loaded by me, but rather by the devise gem it's not easy to  set `@user.virtual_attribute_name_here = "Some thing"`. If I found that the `@user` (or `resource` as devise calls it) is being set in the same method across devise controllers I could override it, but I'm having a hard time determining where devise loads the user.

Comment: If you're worried about the user that's set by Devise then just use that for the virtual attribute by doing current_user.virtual_attribute_name_here = "Some thing"    Once you've edited the Devise controller to go through your controller you can set the User however you like and dont need to reconfigure all devise controllers that may touch it.

Comment: Thanks for you input @bkunzi01. You're right, I just need to find a place to inject myself in the process and set a virtual attribute for `current_user`. But where to do that? It's not that obvious because the user is loaded somewhere in the middle. I can't override the initial method (like `create` or `update`) and then call `super` (as exemplified in the bottom of my question). Because at that point the user is not loaded yet. So I need to inject myself somewhere after the initial controller method, but before the model gets involved.